# Having trouble clicking with pyautogui on website

Tags: python

I have been trying to automate a game, but for some reason, I cannot click on the game. It is one of those games where icons fall down, and you need to click them. There is also a bomb and if you click it, you lose. Here is a screenshot:
[image: Figure 1. Example of game.]

Here is my code:

```
import pyautogui
while True:
    x,y = pyautogui.position()
    pyautogui.click(x, y, button='left')
```

What this does is it tells the script where the mouse is currently at, then clicks there. When I go over to the game window, it doesn't do anything. I have no idea why this is happening. I double checked that my code was still going, too. 
Can someone please help me?

Comment: does click register as `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`?

Comment: i dont know. You can probably find it somewhere on the pyautogui pipy site.